# Multi-Site Manager / Matrix / Image not appearing

Tags: matrix, multi-site-manager

I'm assisting a colleague and for the life of me I can't understand what's happening.

SCENARIO

-Multi-site (full site and mobile version)
-Attempting to share "company information" social icons from the Full website to the Mobile site.
-Using Matrix 2.4.3 and EE 2.5.3

CODE

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="company_info" limit="1" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" entry_id="2" site="default_site"}
{company_social_media}{image}<a href="{url}" rel="publisher" target="_blank"><img src="{site_url}{image}" alt="{alt}"/></a>{/company_social_media}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

WHAT IS WORKING

We are getting the {ALT} and the {URL} but NOT the image. We were using "ed_img_sizer" and stripped that code out to just hold the {image} (as shown above) to no avail.

### #

Does anyone know if this is a known bug or would a simple upgrade fix these issues? Doesn't make any sense why we would get the URL and ALT but not the IMAGE source.

Thanks for the help...

Comment: Hey Mark - is Lyles your colleague?  I'm helping him out here: https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/images_not_appearing_when_sharing_with_multi_site_manager_matrix :)

Comment: He is! Sorry maybe I should have just posted this question on your forums. My bad on that. Didn't know if we would get a response soon enough or not :/

Comment: Oh, no worries, Mark.  I watch both places rather fanatically - by email subscription.  I'll keep the troubleshooting over on GetSat since I already answered there.

Comment: Right on :) I'll post the findings here for others to see :D

Comment: Mark, once you get the final solution can you post it here for others to find. Will be helpful and after you post your solution you can accept it as the correct one 48 hours later.

Comment: Will do mate! Sounds like the new update may fix it, I haven't been able confirm this yet, but will shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this before in the same scenario - in my issue the global variable {file_dir} would not parse in child sites - This was filed as a bug and got a resolution here (ps i dont think matrix is effecting it...)

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18265

For people without access to the ee bug tracker

```
Open system/expressionengine/libraries/File_field.php and find this code on line 582:
$this->_upload_prefs = $this->EE->file_upload_preferences_model->get_file_upload_preferences(
    $this->EE->session->userdata('group_id')
);
```

And REPLACE it with this:

```
$this->_upload_prefs = $this->EE->file_upload_preferences_model->get_file_upload_preferences(
    $this->EE->session->userdata('group_id'),
    NULL,
    TRUE
);
```

I believe this is down as fixed in the next version, but this solved the issue for us

Cheers

Comment: THANK YOU! Not a bug with Matrix but with EE (not surprised) and THIS FIXED IT! Thank you soooo much!